# pgfplots: filled markers without border

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to draw a PGF plot with markers only. I want the markers to be filled squares, but pgfplots keeps adding a differently colored border to these marks.

How can I stop that from happening? I want plain filled squares consisting of one color each.

[image: what I don't want]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[tiny]
\addplot[
    mark=square*,
    only marks,
    mark options={draw=none}, % this line does not do anything
    scatter] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to play with `scatter/use mapped color` option; in this case, to "remove" the border, you can set both `draw` and `fill` with the same color or you can set the `draw opacity=0`. The latter method makes markers' size narrow as the border is removed while the former method keeps the markers' size.

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[tiny]
\addplot[
    mark=square*,
    only marks,
    scatter,
    scatter/use mapped color=
        {draw opacity=0,fill=mapped color}% to remove the border
        %{draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color}% for same size
    ] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to get rid of the border entirely? In a situation where the marks are tightly aligned, the border messes up measurements. Perhaps using a custom mark...

Comment: @Jake: I thought about that possibility, but then the marker would be narrow. Since no clues are provided on that side I preferred to keep the same size for markers. Maybe I'll edit the answer for providing both solutions.